# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu and upstart logging permissions

Tags: logging, upstart, setuid, setgid

I have set up this upstart script on a Amazon Ec2 Ubuntu 12.04 TLS instance for executing a node.js application. The script uses setuid and setgid.

It works fine without using `setuid` and `setgid` but when I use them if fails because the process can't write to /var/log/myapp.log (which is the path I want to use for logging) due to a permission denied error.

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 13: /proc/self/fd/9: cannot create /var/log/noommi.log: Permission denied
```

I'm using the default user "ubuntu" for executing the script which is the same user I log in to the machine (I know it would be better to user other user)
As I see ubuntu user belongs to adm group which is a group included in /var/log.
By executing `ls -la` (using "ubuntu" user) this is the result for var/log:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 root      root      4096 Oct 15 12:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root      root      4096 Oct 12 21:44 ..
```

This is the content of script /etc/init/myapp.conf:

```
description "start and stop myapp"
version "1.0"
author "Me!"

start on filesystem and started networking
respawn


env HOME=/home/ubuntu/myapp

#Run the script using ubuntu user instead of root.
setuid ubuntu
setgid ubuntu
script

export HOME=$HOME
chdir $HOME
env PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env NODE_ENV=development

exec /usr/bin/node server.js > /var/log/myapp.log 2>&1

end script
```

What should I do in order the script could write the log in /var/log?

Answer (score 0):

remove `> /var/log/myapp.log 2>&1` from exec

upstart will log to file: `/var/log/upstart/myapp.log` (owner:root)